# Could you explain this signed fixed point number equation?

Tags: arithmetic

[image]
How do I interpret this equation?

> Decimal value of signed fixed point number
>   $-2^3+2^0+2^{-1}+2^{-2}$
>   $$ V = (-1)^{b_{N-1}}\times 2^{N-P-1} + \sum_{i=0}^{N-2}(b_i\times 2^i)\times 2^{-P}\,.$$

$N$ is the number of bits. The point is at a fixed position, $P$ from the right.

Another question: why is it $-2^3$ instead of just a minus sign in front of $2^0$?

Comment: (for the minus part:) Read https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two's_complement  and see if it makes sense then.

Comment: @RanG. : The integer part (1001) is [math]-2^3+2^0 = -7[/math]. If you take 7 in binary 0111 and take 2s complement then you get 1001 (=-7) as well. So the integer part is always 2s complement? But how about the equation?

Comment: Negative numbers are determined using the two's complement method. For positive values: each digit has a value. To the left of the point, the values increase: 1.0  =1 ;  10.0 =2 ; 100.0 =4; etc.  Didgits to the right of the point has a decreasing values: 0.1 =1/2; 0.01 =1/4 ; 0.001 =1/8; etc.  Combine the two ideas (the value + tow's complement) and you've solved the meaning of the formula.